# What is Algebraic Graph Combinatorics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

**Combinatorics** is a branch of pure mathematics concerning the study of discrete (and usually finite) objects. It is related to many other areas of mathematics, such as algebra, probability theory, ergodic theory and geometry, as well as to applied subjects in computer science and statistical physics (as defined here
 [Wikiversity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Combinatorics&ved=2ahUKEwj3sLKYlJ_nAhVb73MBHWZmDWMQFjAJegQIDhAh&usg=AOvVaw2GyRUVWIZeoAVbo5j_EcyP)).

> My work basically deals with framing some formulae to find number of edges  of the graph formed by combinations of two or more different graph under some graph operations,  and these graph operations also form some algebraic structures like monoid etc. For instance, i can find the number of edges in a graph $G$ which is formed by the combination of two graphs namely, $G_1$ and $G_2$, i.e., $G=G_1\star G_2$.

Now, i want to give a title to my work. But i am bit confused as to what word or, phrase or, sentence will match such works the most? I am thinking of a phrase 'Algebraic Graph Combinatorics'  as a title. But i am not sure whether such a phrase is grammatically or, Mathematically correct?

Comment: Algebraic graph theory.

Comment: Algebraic combinatorics and algebraic graph theory are the two fields closest to your topic I would say. The algebraic refers to the approach while graph theory and combinatorics deal with the topics that the approach is applied to. I think you are definitely more on the algebraic graph theory side, as you do not apply your theorems to anything in combinatorics. Combinatorics concerns itself mostly with counting objects, I took a course in combinatorics and graph theory because they overlap so much. Tools from combinatorics are useful within graph theory. Both fall under discrete mathematics.

Comment: @Wesley Strik I think you pointed right . Yes, haven't been able to apply the theorems of algebra in calculating the number of edges. Here, i am also trying to establish a good link between combinatorics and algebra using graphs (here the graphs are the elements in the algebras).

Comment: I like how algebra reduces any object we wish to study to a clear structure with a given set of rules. The trick to then identify them with morphisms, it is just lovely.  If you wish to draw parallels between graph theory and combinatorics I think the best way is to show how the graph are in a way... counting something. The questions in introductory combinatorics are always " but, what are we in fact counting?"  or rather" is there a different way of counting the same objects?" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algebraic graph theory.

Within the field of discrete mathematics one often treats the topics of graph theory and combinatorics. These two fields have some overlap as combinatorics is used within graph theory and provides examples for it. Combinatorics mostly deals with counting, both as a means to an end and for the sake of counting. Think of inclusion-exclusion, recursions and counting problems. Graph theory often gets linked to Euler, how he used this approach to solve many problems. It is essentially about graphs and their properties.

A useful tool within these fields (and many others) is algebra. Algebraic refers to the fact that methods from algebra are mainly applied to a particular field or topic. Take for instance algebraic topology, algebraic geometry, algebraic combinatorics and algebraic graph theory. Algebra is an immensely powerful tool, and, in itself a very interesting abstract topic to study.

I therefore think that you are doing algebraic graph theory.